# Solving $u_{yy} + (2-x)u_y - 2xu = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the pde
$$
 u_{yy} + (2-x)u_y - 2xu = 1
$$
so if I treat $x$ in the coefficients as arbitrary but fixed it is equivalent to solving the ode
$$
 y'' + (2-x) y' - 2x y = 1.
$$
For the homogenous part $y'' + (2-x) y' - 2x y = 0$ I have to solve the characteristic equation
$$
 \lambda^2 + (2-x)\lambda - 2x = 0
$$
which has solutions:
$$
   \lambda_{1/2} = \frac{2-x}{2} \pm \sqrt{ \frac{(2-x)^2}{4} + 2x } = \frac{2-x}{2} \pm \sqrt{ \frac{x^2 + 4x + 4}{4} } = 
\frac{2-x}{2} \pm \frac{x+2}{2}
$$
But I have difficulty finding a particular solution, any hints?

Comment: You can't use the characteristic equation unless you have constant coefficients.

Comment: The coefficients are effectively constant since the derivatives are with respect to y. For a particular solution, use the method of undetermined coefficients with a trial solution y_p = A.

Comment: Also, check your work for lambda 1/2. I don't think your expression is quite right.

Comment: @AlexZorn: Thank you, there was some error. Okay, I will try the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: If I guess $u(x,y) = Ay + B$ and substituting I get $2A - Ax - 2Bx = 1$ and so $x=0$ yields $A = 1/2$ and $B$ arbitrary and $x \ne 0$ yields $A = 0$ and $B = -\frac{1}{2x}$, and so $$u(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} -1/(2x), & x = 0 \\ 1/2y+B, & x \ne 0 \end{array}\right.$$ for arbitrary $B$.